# Extracting and summarizing data from interactive histogram selection in R

Tags: r, plotly, histogram

I want to create an interactive histogram using plotly (or other package if better suited) in R from data similar to this example set:

```
test<-data.frame(sex=c("m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m"),weight=runif(80,5,9))
```

I want to show two overlayed histograms of weight distribution per sex with some summary statistics such as standard deviation, mean, number of samples, all per sex as well as globally.
Also I want to be able to make a selection preferably using a range slider or selection box while updating these summary statistics to the selection. Then I want to be able to add a variable to the original dataset to indicate if a sample is part of the selection.
Thanks for any help! Even if it's just pointing to a relevant online resource, I'm struggling to find one that tackles a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

@DataZhukov this is a revised answer based on your larger data sample. Per reply I removed the side-by-side (think age pyramid) and show how to use `{plotly}`  for histograms.

While `{plotly}` supports interactivity, it is based on the concept of a "static" html-webpage. This means that no "active" calculation is done on the client side/user viewing the page.
For simple stats/summaries you can look into `{crosstalk}` & [SummaryWidget](https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/widgets.html) to enable (some) "dynamic" update (i.e. client side calculations).
For a full fledged dynamic select/filter/recalculate type of interactivity, `{shiny}` is the way to go. (But that is another ballgame.)

`{plotly}` allows you to place text annotations "freely", by specifying the `add_text()` layer.
I construct this from your data. You can also just define it by hand in form of vectors.

If you use data frames as your input data structure, note that `{plotly}` uses the tilde notation (`~`) for the variable.

```
test<-data.frame(sex=c("m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m","m","m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f","m"),weight=runif(80,5,9))


# calculate mean, sd, etc based on given data
# note you can also define this with simple vectors
total_stats <- test_df %>% 
  summarise(SAMPLE = n(), MEAN_WEIGHT = mean(weight), SD = sd(weight)) %>%
  mutate(sex = "m+f")

group_stats <- test_df %>% group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(SAMPLE = n(), MEAN_WEIGHT = mean(weight), SD = sd(weight))

my_stats <- bind_rows(total_stats, group_stats) %>%
  mutate(LABEL = paste0(sex, " sample size: ", SAMPLE
                        , " with mean ", round(MEAN_WEIGHT, 2)
                        , " and SD ", round(SD, 2)
                        )
         )

# format your text, e.g. font face and size ---- format to your liking
tf <- list(
  family = "sans serif",
  size = 11
)
```

The `{plotly}` call to construct the "pyramid" side-by-side rather than overlapping and adding a text layer to it.

```
test %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  # ------------ plot histogram ----------------------
  add_histogram( x = ~weight, color = ~sex
                ,nbinsx = 20       # set the number of bins you want/need
                ) %>%
  # ------------ add annotation layer ---------------
  ## I provide x, y positions as vector, you could add and place
  ## each label as its own layer, i.e. add_text() call
  add_text(data = my_stats
           ,x = c(5.2, 6,6.3), y = c(6, 5, 4.5)
           ,text = ~LABEL
           ,name = ""      # left empty as we do not need to name the layer
           ,textfont = tf
           ,textposition = "right"
           , showlegend = FALSE
  ) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title =""))
```

This yields:

[image: plotly histogram]

Obviously, you can freely define the x,y positions of your text annotations.

The default behaviour puts the count-bars side-by-side. If you want to force the "overlaying" behaviour, you can plot 2 histograms and force these 2 graphical layer to overlay. For the latter, you need to set the mode in the `layout()` layer. I put an alpha transparency as well, as you may have overlapping counts in your data sample. Text placement, etc follows the principles shown above.

```
# split test data frame in a male and female df
males <- test %>% filter(sex == "m")
fems  <- test %>% filter(sex == "f")

plot_ly(
     alpha = 0.5     # set alpha to ensure visibility on overlapping counts
   , nbinsx = 20     # set number of bins
  ) %>%
#------------ add a histogram layer per group -------------------
  add_histogram(data = males, x = ~weight, name = "male") %>%
  add_histogram(data = fems,  x = ~weight, name = "female") %>%
#------------ tweak layout --------------------------------------
  layout(
    barmode = "overlay"   # to change side-by-side default to overlay
  )
```

[image: forcing overlaying histograms]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, helps me at least part of the way. I edited my question to show the example data set to more closely resemble the actual data I plan on using, it should be two histograms though, not the pyramid graph you propose here. Also, do the SD and Mean in your answer update with the selection? It seems not to me, also I'm still unclear on how to then extract or indicate which is the selected data on the graph. I've been experimenting with shiny to get this done but to no succes.

Comment: I revised my answer for ploty. The level of interactivity is - in simple words - limited to manipulating the way it is presented (e.g. you can select the layer male/female to show/not show or zoom in). There is no "active" recalculation on the client side (i.e. static). There is some support with html widgets for this. However, if you want to combine your plot and such widgets, you need to use a `{crosstalk}`-compatible widget (which are limited right now). If you want to use active filtering of the data and recalculating the stats (:= dynamic), shiny is the way to go. Good luck.